# Import maven repository in sbt project

Tags: scala, maven, dependencies, sbt

I want to import a library for my sbt project.

Maven repository where the library is stored: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/avulanov/scalable-deeplearning/1.0.0

I tried (and many others resolvers):

```
    resolvers += "Maven Repository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/"
    libraryDependencies += "avulanov" % "scalable-deeplearning" % "1.0.0"
```

**Questions:**

Can someone explain how to import this library?

Comment: mvnrepository is **NOT** a usable Maven repository it's only a search engine...

Comment: Ok, I tried to find out how to import the repository contained in the "Repository" column:  "Spark Packages Repository" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/" but it doesn't work. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just to find how to import this library.

Like khmarbaise said :

> mvnrepository is NOT a usable Maven repository it's only a search engine

In fact the correct repository is "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
(as explained in the maven page in the "Repository" column)

**Solution:**

```
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repository" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/"

libraryDependencies += "avulanov" % "scalable-deeplearning" % "1.0.0"
```